# horizontal scroll view that snaps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I am looking for a way so that when I swipe left or right on a horizontal scroll view it will snap to one of the elements in the center, assuming that three elements (in this case a UIImageView) will be shown at once. How do I do this?

Comment: Snap one of the elements in the center ? What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't scroll loosely, but it strictly centers to the next element

Answer (score 2):

Turn on the pagingEnabled property for UIScrollView

If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls. The default value is NO.

You can set it programatically or in interface builder.

Comment: can you clarify what scroll view's bounds means?

Comment: If your scroll view is 100 points wide and it's content view is 1000 points wide, it will snap to multiples of 100. So it would appear that the scroll view has 10 pages and it will snap to each 100 point section of the scroll view.

Comment: #Randall - What if I want the scroll view to stop at multiples of 50 instead of 100? can u help me with this plz?